# Windows Compare filenames and delete 1 version of the filename

Tags: windows, powershell, file, batch-file, cmd

I have several hundred folders where I will have multiple files called filename.ext but also another file called filename.ext.url

I need a way of checking if filename.pdf.url exists does filename.ext exist. If they both exist delete filename.ext.url

I can't just do a search and delete all *.url files as they will be needed if the normal file does not exist

I then need to repeat that in all subdirectories of a specific directory.

I don't mind its its a batch script, powershell script that does it or any other way really. I'm just stumped on how to do what I want.

Currently I'm doing it folder by folder, manually comparing file names, file size and file icon.

Comment: Do you want `filename.url` to be deleted if `filename` exists **in the same directory** or if `filename exists **anywhere in the subtree**?

Comment: Do you want this to happen in the main directory and each of its subdirectories, or just each of the subdirectories within a main directory. Please [Edit] your question to clarify this and each of the previous comments.

Comment: @Stephen, sorry, they should have all been "filename", poor edit on my behalf there.

Comment: @Magoo, same directory only.

Comment: @Compo, in each directory including the main but only in 1 directory at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach ($file in ls -Recurse c:\files\*.url) {
    if (ls -ErrorAction Ignore "$($file.PSParentPath)\$($file.basename)") {
        remove-item $file.fullname -whatif
    }
}
```

remove whatif when ready to delete.
the basename removes the extension, so if they are all .ext.url then it will check if that file exists. It also removes the path, so we pull that as well.

an alternative way (that more matches what you're explaining) is something like

```
foreach ($file in ls -Recurse "c:\files\*.url") {
    ### replacing '.url$' means .url at the end of the line in Regex
    if (ls -ErrorAction Ignore ($file.FullName -replace '\.url$')) {
        remove-item $file.fullname -whatif
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, copied the wrong set of lines

Get-ChildItem –Path "C:\files\" -Recurse -Filter *.url|
Foreach-Object {
    ### replacing '.url$' means .url at the end of the line in Regex
    if (ls -ErrorAction Ignore ($_.FullName -replace '\.url$')) {
        remove-item $_.fullname
    }
}

Comment: @Muttly, . While `Get-ChildItem -Recurse –Path "C:\files\*.url"` - perhaps surprisingly - would work too, using a separate `-Filter *.url` argument is not only conceptually clearer, but also performs better (because `-Filter` filters at the source).

Answer (score 2):

```
for /r "startingdirectoryname" %b in (*.url) do if exist "%~dpnb" ECHO del "%b"
```

This is expected to be executed directly from the prompt. If the requirement is as a batch line, each `%` needs to be doubled (ie. `%%`).

This also assumes that the `whatever.ext` file is to be in the same directory as the `whatever.ext.url` file.

Note that the filenames that are to be deleted will merely be `echo`ed to the console. To actually delete the files, remove the `echo` keyword.

Test against a test directory first!

[untested]

Answer (score -1):

To check for "filename.ext", check for "filename.ext.", they are the same file.

In CMD.EXE, you can do "IF EXIST "filename.ext." CALL :DoIt

Comment: Thanks but you've missed that some are called filename.ext and some are called filename.ext.url